# How can I configure NGINX to block HTTP and XMLRPC (Wordpress pingback) attacks?

Tags: nginx, ddos

Hey how can I configure my NGINX to block HTTP attacks and XMLRPC attacks?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually this makes much more sense:

`if ($http_user_agent ~ WordPress) { return 444; }`

Returning the status code `444` will tell NGINX to not send any response to the bad requests and just close the connection immediately. This will save lots of traffic and resources compared to sending a 403 page as the other response suggests.

Source: https://javapipe.com/block-wordpress-xml-rpc-ddos-attacks-with-nginx

Answer (score -1):

```
if($http_user_agent ~ "WordPress") { return 403; }
```

This is easy to block and can be done with a simple "if" statement

Comment: It would be even better to use `if($http_user_agent ~ "WordPress") { deny all; }`, as it will log the attempt to error.log

Comment: Returining `403` is not a good idea, as it force nginx to respond the requests. The better return would be `444` which tells nginx to not bother responding.